# Getting error while installing python package scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am try to install scrapy for web scraping in python. But getting an error .

```
Using cached PyDispatcher-2.0.6.tar.gz (38 kB)
ERROR: Error [WinError 225] Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a 
virus or potentially unwanted software while executing command python setup.py egg_info
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 225] Operation did not complete 
successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted software
```

Comment: Maybe your system has virus, that infected somehow archive PyDispatcher-2.0.6.tar.gz, this error message looks like from Windows Defender. Find this archive on your PC and upload to check on virustotal.com. If it will confirmed - first you need to disinfect your PC with antivirus. 
Also, to tell pip not use cached data - use command like `pip install --no-cache-dir`, or search how to purge your pip cache.

Answer (score 0):

How did you try to install it? `pip install scrapy` should work.

Comment: I run pip install scrapy. But did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

it's just an antivirus problem that prevents it from installing certain packages like `scrapy`.

You can turn off your antivirus or watch this video to open virus and threat protection(in windows)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_0_A9D0JeVo